# Is there a way or a browser extension to bring the focus to the highlighted search result in a browser (Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

So that if there is a link, for example, you could press the key and then `[ENTER]` to follow it.

The emphasis is on "highlighted", not just tabbing around a page. Probably not a real technical feasibility unless said item is actually "focusable".

Answer (score 1):

The `TAB` key is something you might want to look into. You can use it to navigate UIs in the entire system (Windows at least, don't know about other operating systems).

In Google search, once you get to the results page, hitting `TAB` will make a little window saying "Skip to main content". You can press `ENTER`, and it will bring you to the first result. After that, you can continue navigating by continuing to press `TAB`. This will bring you to a couple of thinks related to the result, and will then move on to the next result.

[Image of "Skip to main content" in Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ggN.png) (cannot embed posts :( )

Answer (score 1):

In Windows after highlighting the text, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the context menu, then press:

- <kbd>S</kbd>: to search the highlighted text.
- <kbd>T</kbd>: to open the highlighted link in a new tab.
- <kbd>W</kbd>: to open the highlighted link in a new window.
- <kbd>G</kbd>: to open the highlighted link in an incognito window.

Comment: Hm, it still focuses on the CTRL+F search bar, though (also, my keyboard has a context menu key)

Comment: You must close  the CTRL+F search bar for what i described to work.